# Entity not mapped, although mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager

I have 2 projects:

1 for the entities
1 for a web service

While using Hibernate 4.3.11.Final everything was working properly. I have a `hibernate.cfg.xml` where I have all the classes so selecting the entities from the DB was ok using `Query`

Then I changed to Hibernate 5.2.6.Final and I had to change `Query` for `TypedQuery<Entity>` and now it complains that the entity is not mapped.

A test I made calls this code.

```
TypedQuery<Employee> query = getSession().createQuery(
                       "SELECT e from Employee e where e.username = :username");
query.setParameter("username", employee.getUsername());
return query.getSingleResult();
```

And it complains that the entity I'm selecting in the query "SELECT e from Employee..." (not the one defined in the `TypedQuery`) is the one that's not mapped.

Is there a new way to map the entities in 5.2.6? How could I solve this?

The Employee entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@XmlRootElement
public class Employee implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    // Getters & Setters...

}
```

The entry in the hibernate.cfg.xml file is like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
    <mapping class="com.entities.Employee"/>
    <mapping class="all other entities"/>
```

If I change the dependency back from 5.2.6.Final to 4.3.11.Final

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I have no problem and everything works as it should be.

Comment: Provide some code.

Comment: More specifically, please provide the `Employee` entity and how you're specifying that it should be picked up as a mapped class for Hibernate, whether in your spring XML configuration, spring javaconfig, persistence.xml, etc.

Comment: @Naros I updated the question with more info

Comment: Please include how you're bootstrapping Hibernate.

Comment: @Naros What do you mean by bootstrapping? =\

Comment: Where you are starting up hibernate, making it read the configuration file, specifying properties, etc.